Repeater with Post Obj in Timber Twig & ACF
I have a repeater field within a layout:
{% if item.acf_fc_layout == 'showcase_cpt' %} // This is the ACF Layout "showcase_cpt"

        {% include 'template/show-cpt.twig' with {
            'postdata': item.cpt_repeater.post_obj, // This is the Repeater with Post Object within
        } %}

        {% endif %}

Using this for loop in the show-cpt.twig file, I cannot get post data?
 {% for item in postdata %}

        <div class="col-md-4">
       <h2>{{ get_post(item).title}}</h2>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}

I want to advanced on this to further get Postobj fields like custom fields from acf on that particular post obj etc. Looked online but nothing helpful and the Timber documentation lacks on this.
Hoping someone can help

Are you receiving any errors? Did you enable debug mode?

Yh, doesn't do anything
